# moving graph using c++ and QWT

Tags: c++, linux, qwt

hello every one i want to ask that how can i plot a moving graph using qwt as i am new to qwt so i dont have any idea

like i want a curve. my data is continuously coming. that is i want two adjacent points to gradually join by curved line hope you people understands what i am trying to say
is there any way to do this

kindly help me i will be very thank full to you people

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer with 50ms period (25Hz frequency) and update the plot data on timers `timeout` signal.

EDIT: I looked at the QwtPlot closer. I assume that you use it with [QwtPlotCurve](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html). I think you can use its [SetRawData](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#35533bd778842cf45b283a2baf5ff4a4) method and every 50 miliseconds (or longer, depends on what you need) update your data arrays, then replot your graph with the [replot](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot.html#7b094e29b8e92b00e36517d0d7633c4b) method. Don't know if you have to invoke SetRawData on every update, according to [Set Data](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#1dc2caaddb1733703b5fcfbe19f29fe8) description, you don't.

Or you can use AutoReplot. If you enable it with [QwtPlot::setAutoReplot](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot.html#654934ec2ad167101dacb5174f5172d6), invoking [QwtPlotCurve::SetData](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html#1dc2caaddb1733703b5fcfbe19f29fe8) with new data set should replot it automatically.

Comment: ok sir thank but sir wont it show the whole graph at once  then after interval of 50 sec show the next values??

Comment: @randy: I added more info, hope it helps